# Can I use both configuring SI with annotation in java file and xml?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Last year, spring integration released 4.0 version for us to configure using annotation without configuring in XML files. But I want to use this feature using the existing XML configurations.

So I wrote the code using spring boot and integration annotation

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages ={"com.strongjoe.blue"},excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX, pattern={"com.strongjoe.blue.agent.Bootstrap*"}))
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ImportResource( {"${context.agent.path}context-bean-*.xml",      // Context Configuration 
                  "${project.agent.path}context-properties.xml" } )  // Project Based Chain configuration 
public class AgentStarter implements CommandLineRunner{  

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());



    @Lazy
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="blue-hub-start-channel", outputChannel="blue-hub-route-channel")
    public <T> BlueMessage<T> startJob(BlueMessage<T> msg) {
        logger.debug("BluE Hub Agent started :{} [phrase:{}]", System.currentTimeMillis() , "prototype-version");
        return msg;
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="blue-hub-end-channel")
    public <T> BlueMessage<T> endJob(BlueMessage<T> msg) {
        logger.debug("BluE Hub Agent ended :{} [phrase:{}]", System.currentTimeMillis() , "prototype-version");
        return msg;
    }



    @Bean                      
    @Transformer(inputChannel="blue-normalized-channeel", outputChannel="blue-output-channel")
    public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer JsonToMap( ) {
        return new JsonToObjectTransformer( List.class );
    }

    @MessageEndpoint
    public static class Echo {
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="blue-output-channel")
        public void stringEcho(Message message) {
        }   
    }   


    @Autowired
    Gateway gateway;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AgentStarter.class);
        app.setWebEnvironment(false);
        app.run(args).close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.err.println("blue-hub-agent started..");
        System.out.println(gateway.sendReceive("gitlab"));

    }
```

And I wrote the definition about every channel I use in the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-4.0.xsd">

    <int:channel id="blue-normalized-channel" />
    <int:channel id="blue-header-channeel" />
    <int:channel id="blue-request-channel" />
    <int:channel id="blue-output-channel" />
    <int:channel id="blue-gitlab-request-prepare-channel" />
    <int:channel id="blue-hub-start-command-channel" />

    <int:channel id="blue-hub-start-channel"/>
    <int:channel id="blue-hub-end-channel" />
```

But I got error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:8090.blue-hub-start-channel'.
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:223)
```

The reason will be, I think, 
that spring bean in XML file and spring bean with the annotation has different context. So I think that even if blue-hub-start-channel is subscribed by the service activator named "startJob", it got error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is no `blue-hub-start-channel` definition in the xml... So how should it be able to detect it. They are all in the same context so that isn't an issues. One thing that is missing is a `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation for a spring boot application (Or use `@SpringBootApplication` and remove the `@Configuration` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I changed my question. and you can see the definition of the  channel. Like you said, I already tried keeping adding and removing the annotations you mentioned above.

Comment: Try without `@Lazy`.

Comment: @M.Deinum original version of this was the one without "@Lazy"

Comment: I nowhere see your definition for the gateway...

Comment: @M.Deinum I think I will solve it with Gary Russell's answer. Thanks for your interests!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotating `@ServiceActivator` on @Bean is not for POJO Messaging. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15193).

When you annotate `@Bean`s this way, you have to provide an appropriate object (`MessageHandler` in this case).

For POJO style annotated methods, the annotation must be on a method in a `@Bean` method (like you have on this one...

```
@MessageEndpoint
public static class Echo {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="blue-output-channel")
    public void stringEcho(Message message) {
    }   
}
```

... and then declare a `@Bean` for Echo.

You can put all your `@ServiceActivator` methods (and `@Transformer`s) in the same `@MessageEndpoint`.

Comment: Thanks again. I spent almost a day trying to solve. I couldn't find the document you linked. If I find it earlier, I would solve in a short time. I am changing the configuration method from XML file to POJO style annotation. I took long time to be accustomed with xml. Latter one  is gonna tough for me. I am worrying about it.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl). It makes java configuration of Spring Integration much easier, especially with Java 8 (lambdas).

Comment: Ok, I will. But I can't use integrationFlow using Java 8's lambdas. Because, I have to use java 7. Thanks!